# Upgrading SQL authentication EF database first to Identity 2

Tags: webforms, forms-authentication, asp.net-identity, identity

We're currently using the old SQL membership (forms authentication) with a web forms project, that uses EF 6 database first.

We'd like to upgrade our membership to Identity 2.0, but have not managed to find anything which walks us through the migration specifically for our scenario of existing db-first model with forms authentication.

I have tried the approach in http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity but this doesn't work as it is code-first and seems to be for Identity 1.

If anybody knows how to do this or has any resources that might help, it would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a YouTube video tutorial which may help you to get some idea in order to achieve your task. Actually this isn't for migrating membership to Identity 2.0, but this video illustrates to use Identity 2.0 with existing database. I hope you can work with your current resources (The given link).

Part 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM

Part 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbSqi3Amatw

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'd already started watching this video but it seems to pertain to an MVC project that doesn't already have the old membership system.

Comment: Yes, you can combine stuff and make it work. The main issue is making this support for database first.